# Magento: category custom layout update (to set new product_list template) is not working

Tags: php, magento

I have some categories in Magento (EE 1.9) for which I'd like to use a different `product/list.phtml` template.

So under Manage Categories, I select the target category and apply the following custom layout update:

```
<reference name="product_list">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/category/list_custom.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

I re-index, cache is disabled, but nothing happens. The product_list template does not change.

It does change if I update `layout/catalog.xml`, which contains the following:

```
 <catalog_category_default translate="label">
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
```

But obviously, editing catalog.xml changes the template for all categories, and I only want to change it for a few.

What am I doing wrong, please?

[image]

Comment: I believe it's been overwritten by another block. Please check where else you'd have another call for "catalog/product_list". I hope it helps.

Comment: I do see several rewrites in other XML files, but the one which results in a change when I edit it is `catalog.xml`. If it is being overwritten by an XML block, is there any way I can make the XML I specify in the Custom Layout Update, above, override everything? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the "real" solution but it's a workaround.

I couldn't get the "setTemplate" to work via the Custom Layout Update, so I set the category display mode to "Static Block Only", then created a static block which calls the new template like this:

`{{block type="catalog/product_list" template="catalog/product/list_custom.phtml"}}`

It works, but is a messy workaround.